# Highlight (select) the last line of text in a multiline TextBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I want my program to automatically select the last line of text in a multiline TextBox.
I've tried the following code to select the first line in the TextBox:

```
Private Sub TextBoxLog_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxLog.TextChanged
   Dim Line As Integer = TextBoxLog.GetLineFromCharIndex(TextBoxLog.Lines.GetLowerBound(0))
   Dim lineLength As Integer = TextBoxLog.Lines(Line).Length
   TextBoxLog.SelectionStart = TextBoxLog.GetLineFromCharIndex(Line)
   TextBoxLog.SelectionLength = lineLength
End Sub
```

How can I modify the above code so that the last line is automatically selected when the text is changed?
I think I just need to change the second line in the above code snippet.

**Note:** The TextBox is set to read-only and is filled with text by Button clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- [GetLineFromCharIndex()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getlinefromcharindex) to get the last line index, using the text length as reference
- [GetFirstCharIndexFromLine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getfirstcharindexfromline), passing the line number you received from the previous call, to get the index of the first char in that line
- call [Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.select) to select text starting from the first char index of the last line to the length of the text, minus the starting position:

Using this form of selection, you won't have exceptions when the Control doesn't contain any text (i.e., when the text is an empty string).
Also, you avoid to use the [Lines](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,682) property: this value is not cached, so it needs to be evaluated each time you use it, parsing - each time - the whole content of a TextBoxBase control.

---

```
Private Sub TextBoxLog_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxLog.TextChanged
    Dim tBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBoxBase)
    Dim lastLine As Integer = tBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(tBox.TextLength)
    Dim lineFirstIndex As Integer = tBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lastLine)
    tBox.Select(lineFirstIndex, tBox.TextLength - lineFirstIndex)
End Sub
```

► Since you're adding text to the TextBox control using a Button, I suggest to set the TextBox/RichTextBox [HideSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.hideselection) property to `False`, otherwise you may not actually see the selected text. If you don't like to have `HideSelection` set to False, then you need to call `[TextBox].Focus()`, in the Button.Click handler, to see the text highlighted.

Here, I'm casting **`sender`** to [TextBoxBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase) (`Dim tBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBoxBase)`), so you can adapt this method to any other TextBox or RichTextBox without changing the name of the Control.

- Both the TextBox and RichTextBox classes derive from TextBoxBase, so the code works for both
- The `sender` argument represents the Control that raised the event.